# Avoid Null values in Coalesce

Tags: sql

I have used coalesce to produce results but got duplicate rows with Null values.

Sample tables as below:

```
Table - Student             
ID  Student Subject id  Subject   Grade id
100 Peter   200         Chinese   201
101 Mary    300         English   302
102 Sam     400         Maths     403
103 John    900         Music   

Chinese Table       
Subject id  Grade id    Grade
200         201         Good
200         202         Average
200         203         Poor

English Table       
Subject id  Grade id    Grade
300         301         Good
300         302         Average
300         303         Poor

Maths Table     
Subject id  Grade id    Grade
400         401         Good
400         402         Average
400         403         Poor

Select Id, Name, 
Coalesce (chinese.grade, english.grade, maths.grade) 
from Student 
Left join Chinese On student.id = Chinese.subjectId AND student.gradeId = Chinese.gradeId
Left join English On student.id = English.subjectId AND student.gradeId = Enlgish.gradeId
Left join Maths On student.id = Maths.subjectId AND student.gradeId = Maths.gradeId

Result
ID  Student Subject     Grade 
100 Peter   Chinese         Good
100 Peter   Chinese         NULL
101 Mary    English         Average
101 Mary    English         NULL
102 Sam     Maths           Poor
102 Sam     Maths           NULL
103 John    Music           NULL
```

I am not sure where the duplicated row of Null values came from, just want to know how can I avoid giving null values by using coalesce?

Comment: you should show us the full select  statement.  kinda hard to tell you what is wrong when you don't show the broken part.

Comment: Hi Hogan, edited table as above can you please check.

Comment: Why do you have three different tables? Put all classes in the same table.

Comment: Thanks for editing to the full query!  @DavidScarlett has all the answers I would give in an answer, read his answer and comments carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select s.id,s.name,s.[subject],
coalesce(coalesce(coalesce(c.grade,e.grade,c.grade),e.grade, coalesce(c.grade,e.grade,c.grade)),m.grade,coalesce(coalesce(c.grade,e.grade,c.grade),e.grade, coalesce(c.grade,e.grade,c.grade))) as grade
from student s
left join chinese c on s.subjectid = c.subjectid and c.gradeid = s.gradeid
left join english e on e.subjectid = s.subjectid and e.gradeid = s.gradeid
left join maths m on m.subjectid = s.subjectid and m.gradeid = s.gradeid
```

result

```
id--name----subject--grade

100 Peter   Chinese Good
101 Mary    English Average
102 Sam     Maths   Poor
103 John    Music   NULL
```

Comment: This one is not appropriate as it will remove the "Music" row in the result which the value NULL should be normal. I just want to remove the NULL value where there are grades in the result for (i.e. Chinese, English, Maths)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the "just want to know how can I avoid giving null values by using coalesce?" part of the question only, since the origin of the duplicate records requires more information than was provided:

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value in its argument list, or `NULL` if all arguments are `NULL`.

So `Select Id, Name, Coalesce (chinesetable.grade, englishtable.grade, mathstable.grade) ...` will still give you a `NULL` grade if all of `chinesetable.grade`, `englishtable.grade`, and `mathstable.grade` are `NULL`. You need to decide what you want to do in that situation. You could either skip those rows:

```
Select * From
    (Select Id, Name, Coalesce (chinesetable.grade, englishtable.grade, mathstable.grade) As Grade from Student where id = id...) As grades_with_nulls
    Where Grade Is Not Null;
```

Or provide a default value as the last argument to `Coalesce`:

```
Select Id, Name, Coalesce (chinesetable.grade, englishtable.grade, mathstable.grade, 'None') from Student where id = id...
```

Comment: Hi David, edited table as above. Knowing that subject Music should be Null in the result after coalesce as there is no grade in the Music Table in the db, but not sure why the other subjects still give duplicated rows with NULL values if not null in the subject tables. And I cannot use "where Grade IS NOT NULL' since it will remove the Music row which NULL should be normal.

Comment: Please post a query that you have actually tried. The query in your question contains errors and could not have produced the results that you are seeing. (Example errors: Joining on `student.id = Chinese.subjectId` rather than `student.subjectId = Chinese.subjectId`, the same for  the other tables, and misspelling `English` as `Enlgish` in one use.) And if you fix those errors, the query does look like it should work without producing the duplicate rows that you are seeing.